# Laravel 5 issues on shared hosting with pathinfo() and unwritable directory

Tags: php, apache, laravel, laravel-5

I managed to get my laravel app to work on shared hosting.

Following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/laravel-news/the-simple-guide-to-deploy-laravel-5-application-on-shared-hosting-1a8d0aee923e), I moved the app files into a `/reddit/` directory outside `/public_html/` and the files inside `/public/` into `/public_html/`

All works well until I try submitting a post, then I get this error

> Can't write image data to path (/images/Q4vQitDu.)

This is the chunk of code it is referring to

```
$orig = pathinfo($info->image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$extension = substr($orig, 0, strpos($orig, '?'));

$newName = '/images/' . str_random(8) . ".{$extension}";

if (File::exists($newName)) {
    $imageToken = substr(sha1(mt_rand()), 0, 5);
    $newName = '/images/' . str_random(8) . '-' . $imageToken . ".{$extension}";
}

$image = Image::make($info->image)->fit(70, 70)->save($newName);
$embed_data = ['text' => $info->description, 'image' => basename($newName)];
```

As you can see, it is generating the image name with the dot but not the `{$extension}` - I have no idea why as it is working locally.

It also says the `/images/` is unwritable, but it is. It exists in `/public_html/images/` and permissions are set to 777

**UPDATE**

I fixed the permission issue by changing the `/images/` url to the full server url `/home/maghnatis/public_html/images/`

But images are still being saved without their extension.

This is `index.php` in `/public_html/`

```
require __DIR__.'/../reddit/bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../reddit/bootstrap/app.php';
```

It is loading files from `/reddit/` dir outside `/public_html/`

I am on PHP 5.5 and these are the loaded modules

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.

instead of `/images/`

I used the full server path `/home/maghnatis/public_html/images/`

And I checked for extension name before sending it to the database

```
$orig = pathinfo($info->image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$qmark = str_contains($orig, '?');
if($qmark == false) {
    $extension = $orig;
} else {
    $extension = substr($orig, 0, strpos($orig, '?'));
}
```